# Get the return from oracle procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

Hi i have already created oracle procedure that only has unions with Selects in it. The procedure is created with this parametars:

```
PROCEDURE mp_prov_preview(pDateFrom      IN DATE,
                            pDateTo        IN DATE,
                            preturn_cursor OUT spdutil.tref_cursor) IS

    v_cursor spdutil.tref_cursor;
```

What i dont understand is how to get the return result set from the procedure. I am using pl sql. I tried in this way, and it executes but the result is not displayed.

```
begin
  -- Call the procedure
  mp_prov_preview('01-oct-2016',
                  '31-oct-2016',
                   :preturn_cursor);
end;
```

PS. I am using plsql

Comment: That is because you are doing nothing with the result. In case of a procedure the "output" result is defined as OUT parameters in your case is `preturn_cursor OUT spdutil.tref_cursor` After call your procedure you have to use this variable and loop on it. Since it is a result of query with just unions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you have a procedure like this:

```
create or replace procedure cursorOut ( pIn  IN     number,
                                        pOut    OUT sys_refcursor
                                      ) is
begin
    open  pOut for select pIn       from dual union
                   select pIn * 100 from dual;
end;
```

In SQLPlus you can call it with:

```
SQL> variable vCurs REFCURSOR
SQL> exec cursorOut ( 1, :vCurs);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print :vCurs

       :B1
----------
         1
       100
```

This will simply print the result of your query; if you need to do something more on the data returned by your query, you can use a PL/SQL block:

```
declare
    vCurs sys_refcursor;
    vVar  number;
begin
    cursorOut ( 1, vCurs);
    loop
        fetch vCurs
        into vVar;
        exit when vCurs%NOTFOUND;
        dbms_output.put_line(vVar);
    end loop;
end;
```

Both ways, you use your `OUT` parameter to get the cursor built by your procedure and then you use that cursor to do something.

The first way is client-specific ( I used SQLPlus), and gives you a variable that you can easily print with the `PRINT` command (again, in SQLPlus).

In the second approach you have a PL/SQL variable that you can use to build a loop and scan every single row to do some operations based on the resulting data. This does not depend on the client, given that only uses PL/SQL.

Comment: You can add an explanation about the OUT parameter since it seems that it is what he didn't understood.